# Which header file needs to be imported for using Parse framework in IOS7?

Tags: ios

I want to use push notifications for my app.I wanted to use PFInstallation class for which needs to import parse framework.Currently I am not getting parse framework in build settings of project.Please help me to get parse framework used for iOS 7?

Comment: have you used #import <Parse/Parse.h> ?

Comment: Hey parse framework is not coming as a option in Xcode 5

Comment: That's because the Parse Framework is not one of the iOS system frameworks, you need to download it and add it to a project yourself.